# ionic app- Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, ionic-framework

Im developing an app with ionic and FB graph api.

when debugging and running on my browser everything seems fine, but on my android device it's not : the funtion "FB.getLoginStatus(...." won't return, and when debugging with adb i get the following error message:

> "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains."

if it's a configuration issue from the facebook developers console, i'de appreciate it if you'll be specific with the fields that should be filled)

parts of my code: (app.js)

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1443507049279750',
      xfbml      : true,
      status     : true,
      cookie     : true,
      version    : 'v2.3'
    });
    console.log("ghghghg");
    isInit = true;
  };


  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     //js.src = "http//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/debug.js";
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

and inside one of the controllers :

```
$scope.fbLogin = function() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                console.log(response.status);

              if (response.status === 'connected') {

                    $User.initUser();

                    $state.go('tab.dash');

              }  
              else{ 

                    FB.login(function (response){
                        console.log("hg");
                        console.log(response);
                    }, {scope: 'email,public_profile,user_friends'});
              }

            });     
    }
```

thanks very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the *info.plist file in the platform directory (ios/facebook_login/*info.plist)
There you need to have:

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>your_appid</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>your_displayname</string>
<key>URL types</key>
<array>
 <dict>
 <key>URL Schemes</key>
   <array>
    <string>fb597296183741619</string>
    </array>
   </dict>
</array>
```